# Switch compound button in android

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview, switch-statement

I am trying to use the switch button in my map activity app

I add the following code snippet in the onCreate method in my project but nothing happens when I click on the switch button

```
      tourSwitch= (Switch) findViewById(R.id.tourswitch);

       tourSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {  
                 if(tourSwitch.getText().toString().equals("ON"))
                 {
                     mapOverlays.remove(3);
                 }

                 else if(tourSwitch.getText().toString().equals("OFF"))
                 {

                     mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                        projection = mapView.getProjection();
                        mapOverlays.add(3, new TourGuide());

                 }
            }
        });
```

If anyone could please help me...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are using the wrong listener. You should use [setOnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener%28android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener%29) (`Switch` is a subclass of `CompoundButton`):

```
tourSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // Do Something
    }
});
```